# UITableViewCell broken after you put a UITableView Inside

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I want to create `UITableView` inside a `UITableView`. I designed the storyboard and set the auto-layout needed. When I check `automatic` on cell row height in `UITableViewCell`. It will resize to 43.5 whatever the height of the cell is. When I remove the `UITableView` it will back to normal. Check the GIF below.

**Expected Output**:
The `UITableViewCell` height refers to constraint.

Edit: I Did this in Xcode **12.0.1**

[image]

Comment: automatic cell height works if all the components (subviews) inside the cell have some implicit intrinsic content size of their own or you have set up height constraint on them and you have set up enough auto-layout constraints such that iOS can evaluate the size of the cell with constraints and intrinsic content size of subviews, but once you bring in `tableView` as subview, `tableView` is inherited from `scrollView` and typically scrollview subclasses does not have intrinsic content sizes of their own and they depend on you to provide some

Comment: kind of size information either by applying height constraint or by restricting its size by providing size to parent view, and because you havent added any height constraint to `tableView` as soon as you add it as subview to cell, iOS has no idea what will be the size of the cell itself hence falls back to original size 43.5 :) hope that helps

Comment: But if I add something like UIImageView, it won't go back to 43.5. Even if I just put it (a new view that has no constraint yet), I treated it just like the table view above. UIImageView is something that has no intrinsic size unless we set the image inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embed table view inside a table view cell is not recommended. Think of the UX of your app when the user will scroll the cells and inside there would be another table view that will the two table views at the same time. You will have two vertical scrolls at the same touch of the screen.

You can have kind of the same functionality using one table view with sections (representing your cells) and rows inside the section (representing your table view inside the cell).

Comment: But we can make the `subTableView.isScrollEnabled = false` & set the table view height based on its content, then the cell will resize based on that sub table view. I tried it, but the result is never optimal.
I think the best practice is NOT embedding a table view inside a table view.